# check if exist something after div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just wondering , what i can do to check if exist anything after a div.
In this example in this cases should return **True** :

http://jsfiddle.net/BsqTg/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/BsqTg/2/

In this case should return **False** :

http://jsfiddle.net/BsqTg/3/

I try to use $('#text').next().length ,but not working.Special for the 1st example.

Comment: Do you mean the next div along or if there is something inside a div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if exists a shorter way, however:

```
var text = $("#text"), 
    hasNext = !!(text.next().length || (text[0].nextSibling && $.trim(text[0].nextSibling.nodeValue)));
```

Basically we check in first place if there is any Element node using `next()` (so, `<br/>` or other elements) if there is, then it's enough. Otherwise, we check if there is any `nextSibling` object, and if it has a value that is not empty string (so any whitespace is not take in account).

Comment: I didn't try, but I believe you can replace `next()` with `prev()` and `nextSibling` in `previousSibling` above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use DOM for this

```
alert($('div#text').is(':not(:last)') || $.trim($('div#text')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue).length > 0);
```

Returns false on your 3rd case:

http://jsfiddle.net/BsqTg/8/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/PLyDe/). I have combined all three cases in one. The code is like this:

```
var $contents = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    // modify the following line to indicate what recon as "something"
    return (this.nodeType == 1 || this.nodeType == 3) && /\S/.test(this.nodeValue);
});
var $text = $(this).find(".text:first");
if (console && console.log) {
    console.log($contents, $contents.index($text), $contents.length);
}
if ($contents.index($text) == $contents.length - 1) {
    $(this).css({
        background: "#F99"
    });
}
else {
    $(this).css({
        background: "#9F9"
    });
}
```

This code does the following:

1. grabs all nodes including text and comment nodes and checks if they are *something*
2. it counts these nodes
3. finds the index of specific element inside that list checks if it is the last one

Answer (score 0):

This is because jquery does not give a convenient way of getting text nodes. You can use container .contents() which does return text nodes, then loop through that to see what there is after the div in question.  To see if a node is a text node it has nodeType == 3.